# Favor variety of words, not repeated words

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Consider these records indexed for full-text search in SQL Server:

```
ID  Content
1   'All about cars, cars, cars'
2   'My house and my car'
3   'A house is a house is a house'
```

When a user searches for the terms "house" and "car" I would like record 2 to be returned as the top result as it seems this is what he/she is looking for.

However, I found no way to achieve this. These queries both rank 1 and 3 above 2 because one of the words is repeated 3 times.

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(TestTable,Content,'ISABOUT(FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"car"),FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"house"))')
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(TestTable,Content,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"car") OR FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"house")')
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run 2 full text searches -- one using AND (to ensure that all words are matched), followed by another using OR.

```
declare @results table (Key int, Rank int, OrderBy int)

-- get rows that match ALL keywords
INSERT @results
SELECT Key, Rank, 1
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(TestTable,Content,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"car") AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"house")')

-- get rows that match ANY keyword, ignoring rows already matched in the previous query
INSERT @results
SELECT Key, Rank, 2
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(TestTable,Content,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"car") OR FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"house")')
WHERE Key not in (SELECT Key FROM @results)

-- select the AND matches first, followed by the OR matches
SELECT * FROM @results
ORDER BY OrderBy, Rank
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's a pity that there's no more straightforward approach for such a basic requirement. I suspect this workaround breaks for 3 or more words.

Comment: @PaulB. Depends on how you need to handle a 3 word query. The 1st query could be `FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"car") AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"house") AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"door")`, then the 2nd query would have ORs instead of ANDs. (Also note the update I just made to my answer to ensure the results are ordered properly.)

Comment: Right, but then again `'All about cars, cars, cars'` gets a higher ranking than `'My house and my car'`, actually even `'Cars & cars'` scores better.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single query, but you could make a table out of the user's search terms, JOIN to content, but only once for each search term, GROUP BY search term and then select the TOP row with the highest COUNT(*).

This doesn't make use of the full-text search, but it can lead to your desired results.